# DropDownMenuItem from Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I can fetch data as stream from Firestore in to `DropDownMenuItem` in my `Flutter` app. But, When I choose one it invokes `!snapshot.hasData` and showing `CircularProgressIndicator` always and does not change.

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: docProvider.fetchLocationsAsStream(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        locations= snapshot.data.documents.map((e) => Location.fromMap(e.data)).toList();
        return DropdownButton(
          hint: Text('Choose Location'),
          value: _selectedLocation,
          items: locations.map((Location loc) => DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text(loc.place),
            value: loc.place,
          )).toList(),
          onChanged: (value) {
              setState({
               dropDownProvider.setSelection(value);
              });
          },
        );
      }
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    },
  ),
```

Result: the top most `CircularProgressIndicator` is still loading after changing the menu
[image]

Comment: Can you add `docProvider` code as well?

Comment: It's similiar to `stream: Firestore.instance.collecion('Shops').snapshots`.  I'm using `get_it` and `provider` packages.